# AWS Sagemaker Endpoint Data Capture in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a sagemaker endpoint, with data capture enabled with a 100% sampling rate.
But after running it multiple times, it is not storing all the inputs to the model,

For instance, after running 3 times, it saves only one time.

[image]